# udev rules work but script failed

Tags: arch-linux, udev, d-bus, rust

I'm trying to detect new HDMI and new USB when they are plugged and notify my Rust program.
Here's my rules:

```
$ /etc/udev/rules.d/80-device-detect.rules
KERNEL=="card0-HDMI-A-1", SUBSYSTEM=="drm", ACTION=="change", RUN+="/home/yuutsuna/scripts/hdmi1_changed.sh"
KERNEL=="card0-HDMI-A-2", SUBSYSTEM=="drm", ACTION=="change", RUN+="/home/yuutsuna/scripts/hdmi2_changed.sh"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="add", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", RUN+="/home/yuutsuna/scripts/usb_added.sh"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="remove", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", RUN+="/home/yuutsuna/scripts/usb_removed.sh"
```

Here's one of the script:

```
$ ~/script/hdmi1_changed.sh
#!/bin/sh
status=$(cat /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-HDMI-A-1/status)
busctl --user call com.u2p.DeviceListener /com/u2p/DeviceListener com.u2p.DeviceListener1 NewDevice ssss "HDMI" "$status" "0000:02.0" "test"
```

The USB ones are the same but I don't need to get the status.

So far here's what I know/did:

- Running the script crash when my Rust program is not running (That's ok)
- Running the script manually while the program is running works fine and the program receive the message from the DBus.
- When I unplug/plug one of the HDMI while the program is running, **it fails with code 1**
- I tried to change one of the script to `echo test >> test.log` and **it writes the log fine** without failing so the rule is working
- I tried to change the script header from `#!/bin/bash` to `#!/bin/sh`
- I did `chmod 777` on my directory and the scripts
- I moved my scripts from `/bin` to `~/scripts` did not changed anything

I don't know what to do...
I read udev run as root automaticaly so it should be ok but I have not way to know why it fails.

Comment: Does the script have execute permissions?

Comment: Yes, from the `chmod 777`. Plus when I change the command in the file it's executed without problem

Comment: Maybe you should see what value your script is getting for `$status`; `echo "status=$status" >> test.log`